# How to mock a function in jest or prevent default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to use react-testing-lib to do some integration testing

I want to mock a function like inside my react class called `handleSubmit`

```
handleSubmit(){
 // does some stuff
 // calls an action creator

}
```

I basically want to stub this method, so that it either returns `null`/`undefined` or anything. But I don't want it to actually call the action creator

The reason being I wanted to assert some UI is present and calling the action creator is giving me the error:

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

I have tried to `jest.mock(thismethod)` and jest.spyOn()` too but neither seem to work. I just want it to do something like

```
myFunc() {

}
```

as if it were an empty function and does nothing. How can I stub this?

Comment: Can you post code that you have tried to mock and is not working along-with class containing function?

Comment: Mock store is prepared ?

Comment: @Shruti not really as it's sensitive code. is there not a generic way to do this ?

Comment: @RedBaron could you please help me confirm my understanding: class has function which calls action. You want to test function(though mock) but don't want that action to be called(may be mock action), is that right?

Comment: @Shruti yes that is correct

Comment: @RedBaron please check if my answer works for you

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `handleSubmit` is a prototype method...if it is then you can mock it like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from 'react-testing-library';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit() {  // <= prototype method
    throw new Error('should not get here');
  }
  render() {
    return (<button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>the button</button>);
  }
}

test('MyComponent', () => {
  const mock = jest.spyOn(MyComponent.prototype, 'handleSubmit');
  mock.mockImplementation(() => {});  // <= replace the implementation

  const { getByText } = render(<MyComponent/>);
  fireEvent.click(getByText('the button'));

  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
});
```

Just make sure to implement the mock on the prototype before rendering the component.

Comment: this looks quite helpful. although one thing I'm not sure how to do. how can I mock the implementation to mock an API call and response? basically I want to mock handle submit to call one of my actions called `notify`, notify should then display some UI on the screen. currently I'm just doing `mock.mockImplementation(() => false` but that doesn't call the action and thus doesn't render the UI. does that make sense? is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try below mocking of function and action:

```
//Mock function
 var mockPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(<mock response similar to actual promise response>);
});
functionName = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(mockPromise)

//Mock action
const actions = [];
const dispatchAction = jest.fn((dispatchCall) => {
      actions.push(dispatchCall);
});

functionName()(dispatchAction);
expect(dispatchAction).toBeCalledTimes(1)
```

Comment: I don't see where you're mocking the original actions tho?